# Compute Maclaurin expansion of $f(x)=e^{5x^2}$ and find a type for $f^{(n)}(0)$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I'm practising to improve my skills at solving Taylor-Maclaurin Expansion problems and, currently, I'm trying to solve the following:

> 1) Based on the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$, write $f(x)=e^{5x^2}$ as a power series around $x=0$.
>
> 2) For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find a type for $f^{(n)}(0)$.

**My Attempt:**

1. Using the known expansion of $e^x$, $f(x)$ can be written as:
   $$
   e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}\Rightarrow
   f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(5x^2)^k}{k!}}
   =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{5^k x^{2k}}{k!}}
   =1+5x^2+\frac{25x^4}{2}+\frac{125x^6}{6}+O(x^7)
   $$
2. I have calculated the first 6 derivatives of $f(x)$:

   - $f^{(1)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(0+10x)$
   - $f^{(2)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(10+0x+100x^2)$
   - $f^{(3)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(0+300x+0x^2+10^3 x^3)$
   - $f^{(4)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(300+0x+6\cdot10^3x^2+0x^3+10^4 x^4)$
   - $f^{(5)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(0+1.5\cdot10^4 x+0x^2+10^5 x^3+0x^4+10^5 x^5)$
   - $f^{(6)}(x)=e^{5x^2}(1.5\cdot10^4+0x+4.5\cdot10^5x^2+0x^3+1.5\cdot10^6 x^4+0x^5+10^6x^6)$

   Then, I calculated the value of the derivatives for $x=0$:

   - $f^{(1)}(0)=0$
   - $f^{(2)}(0)=10$
   - $f^{(3)}(0)=0$
   - $f^{(4)}(0)=300$
   - $f^{(5)}(0)=0$
   - $f^{(6)}(0)=15000$

   By observing the above results for, I have come up with: $f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n-2)}(0)\cdot(n-1)$.

**Question:**

The current type I've found for $f^{(n)}(0)$ is based on instinct and observation. Is there a better type or, if not, is there a more rigorous way to find this type?

Comment: @AlexFransisco, your edit altered my question; I never said I want a *recurrence relation*. I've rolled it back.

Comment: Never heard of "type" in such context. Could you show the definition of "type"?

Comment: Maybe *type* was a poor word choice; maybe *equation* or *formula* are more fitting in this context; but *recurrence relation* doesn't describe what I'm looking for @AlexFrancisco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look back at the definition of the MacClaurin series
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5^k}{k!}x^{2k} $$

Since $f(x)$ is even, $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ if $n$ is odd. Otherwise for $n=2k$
$$ f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{5^kn!}{k!} $$

Comment: I might be missing something, but how do you get the fact that since $f(x)$ is even, then $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ if $n$ is odd? Is that a general rule? Or just a consequence of $f(x)$ in this case?

Comment: @BoredComedy $f^{(n)}(0)$ are coefficients of $x^n$ in the power series. An even function's power series expansion has only even powers, therefore the odd coefficients must all equal $0$

Answer (score 1):

Since you have McLaurain expansion, you directly get that $$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\begin{cases}\frac{5^{n/2}}{(n/2)!}&n\in 2\mathbb N\\ 0&n\in2\mathbb N+1\end{cases}$$